# Is my motherboard failing, or is there some other issue?

Tags: windows-8, boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, wifi-driver

So, several months ago I put together my own desktop PC.  I set up a dual boot to Windows and Ubuntu.

Recently, without changing any settings or installing anything new, the wifi stopped working on windows (I use a wifi adapter).  It said it was connected, Network settings showed that it was working and running trouble shooting had no results.  My internet still works on any other device.  I found that removing the adapter from the motherboard and plugging it back in was the only thing that fixed the problem.  Reinstalling the wifi drivers did not help.  I purchased a new Wifi adapter, but the problem persists.

More recently, I had a much more discouraging development.  Sometimes, turning on the computer results in a boot loop: BIOS never starts.  Instead, the monitor turns on as if it got a signal, then immediately turns off.  This loops on it's own indefinitely until I hold down power, hard reset it, and try again.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

I haven't tested much on the Ubuntu side.  It appears that wifi works at least some of the time, but since I've had issues just getting to BIOS I'm not confident the issue is on the software side.

I've also noticed issues with some of the USB ports no longer working, but that seems to be off and on.

Finally, as of a few minutes ago, I booted to windows to discover that everything was running very slowly.  Slow here is a relative word, but I have a Samsung 840 pro SSD and I'm used to applications running nigh instantly, and it was a solid 3 minutes before any of my applications would load.

Anyway, my question is this: Is it likely that my motherboard is failing?  Either way, what steps can I take to try and pin down the problem and figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues with windows 8.1 and wifi I solved it by changing the wifi mode from performance to wifi you need to goto network connections and right click on your wifi connection then properties then configure click the advanced tab and look for wifi config,hope it helps.

Comment: This appears to have worked.  Thank you! This leads me to believe the boot loops are unrelated, but after trying to reproduce it I've noticed that the boot loop is actually quite rare, happening maybe 1 in 10 times, and goes away after a restart.  So, for now, I'm willing to say that this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as with most hardware issues it is hard to narrow down specific causes to pinpoint what the root is without having "spare" parts to swap out.

The wireless problem not working with a wireless adapter is quite common, the first thing you can do is go to the device manager, go to the adapter and disable the power management "allow windows to turn off this device to save power" and do so with all the usb hubs and root hubs that have the option (one type will have it and the other type will not), That should help some.

It's somewhat rare for a motherboard to be bad unless it has bad capacitors or is new (defective from the start), the only clear way to check for bad capacitors is to see if they are swollen, there are pictures of bad and good capacitors on google:

[Google Image Search for "How to find swollen capacitors"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20find%20swollen%20capacitors&espv=2&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=W2aSU_rOFIGuyATx7oLAAQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=989)

I have personally had a LOT better luck with wifi add in cards, notably the ones with antennas connected via wires are my favorite, in general I (personally) have issues with USB being unreliable with fobs of any sort.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've used both PCI cards with antennae and USB ones, it's not a matter of the Wifi cutting out, especially because Windows insists that Wifi is connected.

I will try to turn off the option to "turn off this device to save power" and post my results.  I will also try to isolate any hardware that I can, hopefully.

Could the issue be ram or power related?

Comment: Possible but very unlikely, when you said you used an adapter i assumed you meant JUST usb ones. it would help others if you clarified what types of adapters you have used and what problems you had with what type.

Comment: As for ram and power, to be more specific, ram issues should cause the computer to freeze up or crash, at LEAST causing errors in other programs, power issues are a possibility but once again, you should see symptoms elsewhere.

Comment: OK, well I checked for blown capacitors but I don't see any, unless I missed something.  Certain capacitors are larger than others, but those also have a higher number written on them and all of the ones with the same number seem to be the same size.  As for the Wifi thing, I apologize for not being specific enough.  However, I had thought that BIOS getting caught in a boot loop was the much bigger issue anyway.

Comment: I've tried turning off "turn off this device to save power" and, predictably, the issue persists.

Comment: Was worth a shot, you can test the ram with a bootable ram test program, they are free and there is one on the UBCD which is a good tool to have, power supplies are relatively cheap and can be used to test easily, As from what im reading you cannot reproduce the issue when you want to, which makes it very hard to actually test well. if you COULD test the more reliable way would be a barebones test, unplug EVERYTHING except psu/mobo/processor/ram/monitor (use internal video if you can) boot, if it works then add things until you find something that doesn't, swap parts until the issue is found.